# Is there a way to obfuscate whole Cordova/Phonegap project?

Tags: cordova, obfuscation

I want to know if there is a tool to obfuscate a whole Cordova/Phonegap project or not?
I means whole js files which are related to each others and html ans css files. I's so hard to do it one by one.

Comment: And by obfuscating you mean exactly what? I've never heard of such concept.

Comment: @sanfor: He means, "making the code more difficult to understand" by scrambling names and perhaps changing the code without changing its functionality.

Comment: Check out the post I did on this topic: http://ionicframework.com/blog/minifying-your-source-code/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many of the online Obfuscators. Then I looked at various De-Obfuscators tools online and found they could reverse engineer much of the obfuscated code.

I then found a free trial to a Windows app called JASOB (then bought it). It gives very detailed control of renaming all functions, variables and allowing you to prefix / suffix names. For example I had 4 JavaScript files, they each did some unique work and did not cross boundaries. In one I use something like js_ as the prefix and it renamed all functions and variables to something like js_Mx21() js_Z1Ax().

You can also open up multiple JavaScript files and it will handle the rename across files so if you are using shared vars you will not get burnt. This app also handles HTML and other languages. Before I bought it I emailed them some questions because frankly, the website looks old, but they replied, and I have to say I am very happy with the power of this app.

http://www.jasob.com/

Answer (score 6):

Project obfuscation is the only way variable/function renaming is
coherent across all your files, including HTML, and your code does not
break. Also, it's important that the obfuscator deals correctly with
dependencies, and perform code transformation in a way that guarantees
that the code is not broken.

[JScrambler](https://jscrambler.com) is IMHO the best tool for the job:

- It supports obfuscating all files at once, in a project (any kind
  of project, Cordova included)
- It has special support for Mobile/HTML5, tuning down obfuscation
  not to hurt performance
- It has a bunch of API clients that you can use. I personally use
  the npm version, but there's a Grunt one as well.
- It is generally better than all other obfuscators I know.

A word of care about "uglifiers". Most of them are plain minifiers and
optimisers. They do a good job at that, but a very bad one at
obfuscating. It's usually quite fast to reverse that code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grunt to automate tasks like this, this example Gruntfile.js has "uglification" built into it, which is essentially obfuscation.

http://gruntjs.com/sample-gruntfile

Answer (score 0):

You can't sensibly obfuscate a set of files, one at a time.  You need to obfuscate the set of files collectively, scrambling names/code consistently within the set, preserving the public interfaces they offer to code that invokes them from outside the set, and preserving interfaces to code outside the set, that the set accesses.

The hard part of this is knowing what the "public interface" is.  Unfortunately, one cannot tell this from the code alone; it is determined by the design of the application and the assumptions it makes about services it uses, and services it offers.   So one must first make this public interface explicit by writing it down, or an obfuscation tool cannot work. One way to do this is to specify a set of identifiers that must not be obfuscated.

Given such a public interface specification, our [ECMAScriptObfuscator](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Obfuscators/ECMAScriptObfuscator.html) will obfuscate a set of files mechanically and reliably, both for pure JavaScript files, and for HTML with embedded JavaScript fragments.